# List view customization issue while scrolling

Tags: android

I have the below code which overrides the getView, What i want is always the first row should show some custom view and the item cell below this first will show regular cells. My code works fine without any errors, but when i scroll the first cell get repeat after continuos use of scroll upside down, Please refer the code below, If any one can answer this it be of great help. Thanks

```
 @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            int type = getItemViewType(position);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
            if  (convertView == null && position !=0) {
                System.out.println("inside if " + position);

                //holder = new ViewHolder();
                switch (type) {
                    case TYPE_ITEM:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, null);
                        holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                        holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));

                        break;
                    case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item2, null);
                        holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                        holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
                        break;
                }
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else if(position == 0){

                System.out.println("inside else if " + position);
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);


            }else {
                System.out.println("inside else " + position);

                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
                try{
                holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    System.out.println("caught exception is "+ ex.getMessage());
                }
            }

            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: Can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982989/android-listview-scrollig-too-slow/6983209#6983209

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to overwrite the `getItemViewType` method and return a different int for each type (start with 0!). Accordingly the  [getViewTypeCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29) method should be overwritten too.

But why don't you simply use a [header view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) for your `ListView`?